# Passing data to a SWT dialog using ActionListener

Tags: java, interface

I am looking to pass data to a SWT dialog from it's parent.

- The parent interface has a table and a button, the button will launch the dialog box
- When the user clicks a table row an associated value will be sent to the dialog box which will populate the text fields based on that falue (sql query)

I know this is pretty basic but could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

```
public class PlaybackTab implements StimDialogInterface {
    public PlaybackTab (Shell shell, UIWindow uiw) { 
        this.shell = shell;
        this.uiw = uiw;
    }
    private void stimDialog() {
        StimDialog sdiag = new StimDialog(shell, this);
        try { 
            sdiag.open(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            errorDialog( e.getMessage() ); 
        }
    }
 }

public class StimDialog extends Dialog {
    public StimDialog(Shell parent, StimDialogInterface cInterface) {
        super(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.cInterface = cInterface;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

public interface StimDialogInterface {
}
```